# How to use the new char16_t and u8 types?

Tags: c, unicode, posix, c11, char16-t

c11 improve encoding support with built-in types for utf-8 utf-16 and utf-32.

However I was completely unable to find reference on using them in Standard functions. All I found is how to use them in c++11 not in C.

So how to printf a char32_t for example?

Answer (score 3):

There isn't much to say: C11 only introduced four new standard library functions for working with `char16_t` and `char32_t`, which convert them to/from multibyte strings:

- `char16_t`: [`mbrtoc16()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/multibyte/mbrtoc16) and [`c16rtomb()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/multibyte/c16rtomb)
- `char32_t`: [`mbrtoc32()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/multibyte/mbrtoc32) and [`c32rtomb()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/multibyte/c32rtomb)

With respect to `printf()`, they behave like `uint_least16_t` and `uint_least32_t` types, so you can use the same format specifiers for them:

```
#include <inttypes.h>

char32_t x = ...;
printf("%" PRIuLEAST32 "\n", x);
```

If you want to print the value as a *character*, you will need to use the conversion functions above.

Working with `char16_t` and `char32_t` character and string literals is identical 
in both C11 and C++11.

Comment: Ok, do you mean those new types need to be converted to other types before screened as text? I also disagree with the fact that`char16_t`behave like`uint_least16_t`since`char16_t`doesn’t have a fixed bit width. The bit width depend on the width of the Unicode character beeing handled.

Comment: Yes, if you need to print a character, you will need to convert it into the encoding expected by your output device. Also, §7.28 of the C11 standard defines `char16_t`/`char32_t` in terms of `uint_least16_t`/ `uint_least32_t`. The types are designed to represent *code units*, which have a fixed width.

Comment: Strange, because a UTF-16 character can be longer than 16 bits.

Comment: You're confusing *code units* with the encoding of a *code point* (which may require multiple code units).