# How to handle char16_t or char32_t with printf and scanf in C?

Tags: c, printf, scanf, char16-t, char32-t

If I write:

```
char a = 'A';
printf("%x %c", a, a);
```

it will produce the output "41 A".
Similary when I write

```
char32_t c = U'';
printf("%x %c", c, c);  //even tried %lc and %llc
```

it will produce the output "1f34c L" instead of expected "1f34c "!

Is there something wrong here? How can I print char16_t and char32_t characters onto stdout?

Also, which format specifier should I use to get char16_t / char32_t input from scanf?

```
char32_t c;
scanf("%c", &c); //
printf("%x %c", c, c);
```

this will produce the output "f0 �".

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30528713/13188071) in another question help?

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 partially.. But it is too complex(using c32rtomb). Isn't there a simple format specifier for that job? Also, it did not explain how to use char32_t with scanf.

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB Are you on windows?

Comment: Hmm, I see. Perhaps you could use `wchar_t` but it's UTF-16 on windows and UTF-32 on Linux. Apart from that, I'm not sure. I've never used `char16_t` or `char32_t` and rarely ever used `wchar_t`.

Comment: `char32_t c = '';` =>`char32_t c = U'';`

Comment: @phuclv yup. A typo occurred here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`char16_t` and `char32_t` are nothing special. They are really just `uint_least16_t` and `uint_least32_t`. They do not have that great support.  The only thing they are used for are basically `u` and `U` literals. They may **not** be UTF-16 and UTF-32 - check `__STDC_UTF_16__` and `__STDC_UTF_32__` macros before assuming they are. Only very basic conversion functions are in standard.  In the standard there are only functions to convert `char16_t` or `char32_t` into multibyte encoding, and back. To do *anything* more with them, you *have to* implement it yourself.

C language has really two encodings - *locale dependent* multibyte character representation and wide character representation.

> Is there something wrong here?

The `''` character you typed *in your source file* is interpreted by the compiler as a some implementation specific value. Gcc would make  an UTF-8, then [gcc preprocessor](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Implementation-defined-behavior.html#Implementation-defined-behavior) will shift the values left, so `''` is equal to `(int)0xF09F8D8C` **on gcc** - the behavior of multi-character literals  `'something'` is implementation defined. Then the value of that character is assigned to `char32_t`. That is not at all an UTF-32 value.

> How can I print char16_t and char32_t characters onto stdout?

Convert them to multibyte string. Then just print it with `%s`.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <uchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <locale.h>
int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8");
    char32_t c = U'';
    char buf[MB_LEN_MAX + 1] = {0};
    mbstate_t ps;
    memset(&ps, 0, sizeof(ps));
    c32rtomb(buf, c, &ps);
    printf("%s\n", buf);
}
```

Printing data is **locale** dependent, as printing is done in the locale specified by the user. The default locale is `C` and has no UTF support. So first you have to set your locale to something utf compatible. Then call `c32rtomb`. Note that stream chooses encoding at the first time it's printed in `glibc` - make sure to call `setlocale` *before* doing anything with the stream you want to work with.

> which format specifier should I use to get char16_t / char32_t input from scanf?

None, there is none. You should use `wchar_t` or plain `char` strings to read characters from user in the encoding specified in his locale. Then you can convert to/from `char16_t` and `char32_t` if you want. If you want to specifically read UTF-32 characters, then you have to write it yourself to be sure your code reads `UTF-32` characters. I recommend [libunistring](https://www.gnu.org/software/libunistring/).

Comment: MB_CUR_MAX defined where? My compiler did not found it in uchar.h

Comment: In my code I had actually prefixed '' with U. I mistyped here.

Comment: `My compiler did not found it in uchar.h` It should be in `uchar.h`. Post your compiler, compiler settings, standard  library version. The support for `char32_t` is not great in compilers, rather use an external library.

Comment: The solution code you provided in the end is not working for me. `c32rtomb` is returning -1.

Comment: My compiler - x86-64 gcc 10.2  windows 64 bit machine.

Comment: `MB_CUR_MAX` is defined in `stdlib.h`. But it is a macro variable and not macro constant. So you can't initialize the array with {0}.

Comment: Right, I wanted `MB_LEN_MAX`. `x86-64 gcc 10.2 windows 64 bit` I have no idea what `c32rtomb` on gcc uses behind it. I would suspect `iconv` that uses `libunistring`, but I have no idea on windows. `c32rtomb is returning -1` So check `errno`.

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB I edited the question. The code, __if__ you have `en_US.UTF-8` locale generated, should work.

Answer (score 2):

i have given value in `HEX` format `symbol = 0x0001F34C` there are other ways to solve it to this is how i know check following code in c we cannot print symbol using `%c` or just `printf` [here is explain why to use wchar_t instead of char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27401231/understanding-and-writing-wchar-t-in-c) `char` have UTF-8 encoding and wchar_t have UTF-32 which increases its range

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>
int main() {
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");
    wchar_t symbol = 0x0001F34C;
    wprintf(L"%x %lc\n",symbol,symbol);
}
```

```
output: 1f34c
```

check this following link
[Printing a Unicode Symbol in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43834315/printing-a-unicode-symbol-in-c) , [UNICODE of emoji banana](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f34c/index.htm) , [char32_t](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/multibyte/char32_t)

Comment: For me, it is printing `1f34c ?`. Why so?

Comment: `and wchar_t have UTF-32` on linux, and `wchar_t` is UTF-16 on windows.

Comment: yes on windows. But sizeof wchar_t is 4 bytes! (using online compiler)

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB ```printf("\xF0\x9F\x8D\x8C");``` check if this works or this ->   ```printf("\xD83C\xDF4C");``` as i am not using windows i trying to print it directly